# Immigration and custom delay along with flight delay caused to miss connecting flight

Tags: customs-and-immigration, hotels, delays, missed-flights

Immigration and Customs at ORD Chicago caused us to miss a connecting flight (American Airline), also partly due to technical problems which delayed the flight (British Airways from London-ORD). We had to book hotel room for a night as there no flight for that night. Will the airline take care of expenses of hotel caused due to immigration delays? If yes, which airline is responsible for taking care of expenses ? Incoming flight or connecting flight as both are different airlines and ticket was booked as a single ticket.

Comment: Need lots more info, such as where this occurred, what countries are involved etc...

Comment: You're biggest problem will be trying to get compensation after the fact.  Your best recourse would have been through the airline with the technical fault.

Comment: I would start with the airline that issued the ticket; that is the company with which you have a contract.

Comment: As a practical matter, first ask for help from the one of the two airlines that has the largest presence at the airport. Even if it's strictly not their problem, they should either fix it on behalf of their business partner (and sort out the costs internally afterwards), or point you towards the right desk.

Comment: None of them is obligated to bear your expenses if like you indicate Immigration/Customs were even partly responsible. You are in the realm of [contributory negligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contributory_negligence). In some jurisdictions, the doctrine states that a victim who is at fault to any degree, including only 1% at fault, may be denied compensation entirely. Thus the airline can say since the delay was not entirely it's fault, they will not offer help. I believe you are out of luck unless you get a considerate client service operative from the one with the technical problem.